# Laravel, Ajax and BS3 Dismissible Alerts

Tags: ajax, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5.5, laravel-routing

How can I intercept when an alert was dismissed (data-dismiss=alert button) and, with Ajax, set status = 0 in my notification model?

I use Laravel 5.5 and Bootstrap 3. This is the button that I use for dismiss alerts:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3 has on closed event:
`$('#myAlert').on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
  // do something…
})`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to what you need is in this post also on stackoverflow:

[Ajax request on dismissal of twitter bootstrap alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128665/ajax-request-on-dismissal-of-twitter-bootstrap-alerts)